# Which interface's method got implemented in class

Tags: java, interface, overriding, multiple-inheritance

We know in Java we can't achieve the multiple inheritance but can be achieved by the interface.

Here I am stuck. This is the situation,

```
interface A {
    void a();
}

interface B {
    void a();
}

class AB implements A, B {

    @Override
    public void a() {
//            which interface's method be implemented?
//            Log.d("TAG", "Name of Interface: " + /*get the name of interface*/);
    }
}
```

Please suggest me something.

Comment: it's not "overridden", it's implemented. and it's both, clearly.

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter which interface method is implemented, as there is only one method implemented. It can be refered by any of the interface.